# bltoolkit - adding a property which is not in database table

Tags: orm, mapping, entity, bltoolkit

is there any way in bltoolkit how to add to an entity property which is not mapped to the database table?

something like:

```
[NoMap()]
public string Something {get; set;}
```

?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the MapIgnore attribute

```
[MapIgnore()]
public string Something {get; set;}
```